# How was this paint texture achieved?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to make shapes with a similar texture to this image, but i'm not sure how it was done. I tried making a clipping mask with the texture but it didn't look the same. Please help.[image]

Comment: Hi Emily and welcome to GDSE. There are many things working together to create the expression of this design. The chosen images (looks like concrete architecture), the clipping and placement of the images, the choice of colors, the way the images have been colored, the way the layers have been blended etc. It's hard for us to tell exactly what you are trying to achieve. Could you please post a screenshot of what you have so far?

Comment: not sure what this question is about, but looks like a white background layer then some layers (downloaded) with blending mode Multiply.

Comment: Rafael is basically correct, but in this particular image, the designer used several photos (taken from different angles and distances) of the Museum of Sculpture in Sau Paulo. The photos are each colorized or tinted and then overlayed on top of each other. Any texture is from weathering effects on the concrete. The designer used the museum in a number of other collateral, and seems to enjoy incorporating Brutalist Architecture in their designs. Portfolio sample with p: ( https://www.behance.net/gallery/49542405/Portfolio-Foresti-Design ) and google "brutalism Brazilian Museum of Sculpture"

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use a photo of a texture, there are sites online to download them. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=texture+images
   You also could paint something phisically, and take a picture of it.
2. Convert it to grayscale.
3. Change the mode now to duotone, actually you need a monotone, just use only one ink on the dialog box.
4. Play with the blending modes, probably use multiply for start.

You can also play with the contrast of the image, to make things more transparent slide the white side.

There is a chance the images are also skewed or distorted a bit.

The section with the blue sky could be an additional rectangle with cyan color in it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what step one means. Can you edit it please since it doesn't seem to make much sense.  Did you mean to say "Take a photo of a texture, or find a texture you like"?

Comment: Done... Thanks.